# Picture is blurred on UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uibarbuttonitem

I tried to add a picture on an UIBarButtonItem like this : [image]

---

I did it this way via XCode development interface builder. But, when I launch the application, the picture is blurred like this : [image]

---

I tried different sizes for this "home" picture, but I have always the same problem with all pictures I tried (Not only this one).
Maybe I forgot something, or there is a "perfect size" I missed ?

Thanks in advance !

*********** **EDIT** :** Thanks to dariaa I notice I have to import 2 image : home.png and home@2x.png (For the retina compatibility) ********

Comment: How are you setting the size of the image? It looks like it’s the wrong size by just a couple of pixels.

Comment: What is the size of the icon in pixels? Do you import retina version of the icon in the project?

Comment: Setting the size where ? I have the same icon in 25x25 and 32x32 and 128x128 too.

Comment: Can the reason be that you are using a non-retina image?

Comment: Oh gosh ... That's it ... Believed that retina image was just an image with high resolution, but I didn't notice that I have to include in my project home.png and home@2x.png ... Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you set the image for your `UIBarButtonItem`?
I believe if you use this method you should have no problems:

```
UIBarButtonItem *homeBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:yourImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourSelector:)];
```

This way you do not have to worry about sizes.
Just make sure that you have retina version of the image. (you should have "home-25.png"-25x25 pixels image for non-retina devices (if necessary) and "home-25@2x.png"-50x50 pixels image for retina devices.

Comment: It doesn't display anything ... I set a new navigationBar (By adding it with interface builder, and then, add an item (with interface builder too)) **** EDIT : Tried to link the button to my header, then set image via : [self.homeNavBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home-25.png"]]; and it's blurred too ... ****

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an "image set" in your xcassets directory. Import an image and then right-click and select "New Image Set". Once you do this, right-click again in the image box (the image preview on the right) and select iphone, iPad, etc. and fill in all the scaled resolutions of your image.

Xcode will automatically adapt the correct image to be used based on the screen resolution of the device